# open62541 compatibility with c95

Tags: open62541

I want to write an application for an embedded platform that currently runs c95. Is open62541 backward compatible with c95 ?

I am currently looking to work on an opc ua enabled hardware device and wanted to get some info before choosing to use open62541 for development.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the main page it clearly states "Written in C99 with architecture-specific plugins (POSIX, ...)" -> https://open62541.org/